# How do I get the message content of a channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code but it is returning the message id's instead of the message content

```py
@bot.command(name="jpg")
async def jpg_File(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(699577970117050399)
    messages = await channel.history(limit=500).flatten()
    print(messages)
```

This is what I get from printing messages: `<Message id=937077040878866442 channel=<TextChannel id=699577970117050399 name='memes' position=2 nsfw=False news=False category_id=699624938583359608`

Comment: ```<Message id=937077040878866442 channel=<TextChannel id=699577970117050399 name='memes' position=2 nsfw=False news=False category_id=699624938583359608

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `content` attribute of the `message` object.

```py
async def jpg_File(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(699577970117050399)
    messages = await channel.history(limit=500).flatten()
    print(messages)
    for i in messages:
        print(i.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name="general")
    messages = await channel.history(limit=500).flatten()
    for message in messages:
        if not message.attachments:
            print(message.author, message.content)
        else:
            print(message.author, message.attachments)
```

Comment: While code-only answers may provide a solution to the problem at hand, if you could add an additional description of what the code does and why it goes about it that way, it would go a long way towards helping others understand it and apply it to their own use-case.